# Sqlite .dump handles utf8 characters differently than when manually running the command

Tags: powershell, sqlite

So I'm working with a sqlite3 database using the sqlite3 command line.

I'm trying to dump the entire contents into the database, so I can import them into another database. The problem I'm having stems from this apostrophe, `’`, which is the unicode right single quotation mark.

I've set up a Powershell script to dump the table and then import it in one go.

If I create the dump file in the following way:

```
Get-Content sql_commands -Raw | sqlite3 database.db
```

Where the file `sql_commands` looks like:

```
.output output.sql
.dump
```

Everything works perfectly and the unicode character is kept.

On the other hand if I try the following:

```
sqlite3 database.db .dump | Set-Content output.sql
```

The unicode character is not kept and instead looks like "GÇÖ".

I'm confused as to why this is happening. I want to use the second command because that lets me easily set the filepath as a variable in the Powershell script.

I'd appreciate it if you could give some information as to what the difference between the two commands is and what is going on.

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Re `sqlite3 database.db .dump | Set-Content output.sql`:**

In order for PowerShell to interpret the textual output *from* an external program such as `sqlite3` correctly, `[Console]::OutputEncoding` must match the actual character encoding used by that program.

- E.g, if `sqlite3` outputs UTF-8-encoded strings, first (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`

Whatever .NET string PowerShell decodes the external program's output into is then re-encoded on output with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), using *its* default encoding (which is unrelated to original encoding). Use the `-Encoding` parameter to control that encoding.

---

**Re `Get-Content sql_commands -Raw | sqlite3 database.db`:**

Conversely, when PowerShell pipes (what is invariably) text *to* an external program, that text is encoded using the character encoding stored in the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) , so you may have to set that variable to the encoding that the external program expects.